# Jinja2 vs django templates with cached loader - how does performance compare?

Tags: django, performance, django-templates, jinja2

I'm curious - with the introduction of cached template loader in django 1.2 how does performance compare with the latest Jinja2?

Has anyone tried running tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja is more pythonic (more flexibility) and maybe faster than Django template system, but the performance especially depends on your dev skill, and other parameters.

As explain in Jinja FAQ:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/faq/#how-fast-is-it

Comment: I've rewritten all templates from Django to Jinja2 and got an impressive speedup, but I did not use the cached loader for django templates before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, but a false dichotomy, as you can use Django's cached.Loader and pass it Jinja Loaders to have cached Jinja templates.

Second, template caching isn't just for speed. I'd recommend a cached Loader when DEBUG=False, so you can easily iterate on templates when developing, but for production a cached loader is important because without caching your templates may not be in sync with your code for some period of time mid-deployment.

For example, let's say you change a view's context and update the template, and commit. Now if you git pull and then restart your server, for the time in between git pulling and restarting, the view will 500 because you are serving the new template with the old view code. If you are getting multiple requests per second, that's going to result in production 500s, unless your production deployment method obviates this by using multiple directories.

Comment: Not exactly - Django's cached loader stores them in memory within its process -- so on restarting the server, you have fresh templates. The only problem is making sure custom tags are thread safe, and I'm not sure if Jinja2's templates are considered thread safe for use with the Cached loader.